# Почему не работает super

Tags: java, наследование

```
public abstract class Human  {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String gender;

    public String getName() { return name; } //Возвращает имя
    public int getAge() { return age; } // Возвращет возраст
    public String getGender() { return gender; }// Возвращает пол

    public Human(String name, int age, String gender){// конструктор
        this.name=name;
        this.age=age;
        this.gender=gender;
    }

    public abstract void display();
}

public class Student extends Human {
    private String faculty;

    public Student(String name, String faculty, String gender, int age) {
        super(name);
        this.faculty = faculty;
        super(gender);
        super(age);
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.printf("Student Name: %s \t faculty: %s \n", super.getName(), faculty);
    }
}
```

Ругается на super в наследуемом классе , в чём проблема ??

Comment: у вас нет конструктора у human, который бы принимал String name

Comment: У вас конструктор родителя содержит три аргумента, а вы туда пытаетесь передать по одному

Comment: super(name,age,gender) добавьте и будет вам счастье

Comment: Конструкция `super(...)` может быть только первым действием в конструкторе и приводит к вызову родительского конструктора с соответствующими параметрами. Так как не-приватного конструктора `Human(String str)` нет, то это приводит к ошибке. Для второго и третьего `super`-а для ошибки достаточно уже того, что они не являются первым действием в конструкторе

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Измените это:

```
public Student(String name, String faculty,String gender,int age) {
    super(name);
    this.faculty = faculty;
    super(gender);
    super(age);
}
```

на это:

```
public Student(String name, String faculty,String gender,int age) {
    super(name,age,gender);
    this.faculty = faculty;
}
```